# MySQL Missing Closing Parenthesis

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, create-table

Im trying to fill a Temporary Table with existing Data from another table. The thing ist that the new Table needs an additional Column Called for Ranking.

```
CREATE temporary table if not exists TEMP 
AS (select 1 Rang INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, 
           ID, 
           Name, 
           Punkte 
    from Highscore 
    ORDER BY Punkte ASC);
```

But im getting an error on the word 'Rang'.
I'm using the MySQL Workbench.

Is that syntax allowed or is that just a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot ',' in your query:

```
CREATE temporary table if not exists TEMP AS (select 1, Rang INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, ID, Name, Punkte from Highscore ORDER BY Punkte ASC);
```

Comment: No the ',' didn't fix it... i just got word from a friend that this is invalid syntax anyways, so will have to find a workaround... thanks anyways.